# how to reverse native callbacks inside Unity on iOS?

Tags: ios, callback, unity-game-engine, jit

I use lua in unity3d. My lualib is [KeraLua](https://github.com/NLua/KeraLua).

When run on iOS its throws an error:

```
ExecutionEngineException: Attempting to JIT compile method '(wrapper native-to-managed) PluginImport:callB (KeraLua.LuaState)' while running with --aot-only.

  at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate (System.Delegate d) [0x00000] in :0 
  at KeraLua.Lua.LuaPushStdCallCFunction (IntPtr luaState, KeraLua.LuaNativeFunction fn) [0x00000] in :0 
  at PluginImport.Start () [0x00000] in :0 

(Filename:  Line: -1)
```

I checked the code:

```
public static void LuaPushStdCallCFunction (IntPtr luaState, LuaNativeFunction fn)
{
    IntPtr pfunc = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate (fn); // the iOS recognize this line is  JIT compile method
    NativeMethods.lua_pushstdcallcfunction (luaState, pfunc);
}
```

Is there a good method to reverse native callbacks inside Unity on iOS?

Comment: Please use unity3d tag for this kind of questions. The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity.

Comment: I find a way to resolution this.

Comment: If you have resolved the issue, you might post the answer and accept it. My comment above is to warn you that before posting any question on StackOverflow, please spare some time checking the tags you choose. If you choose a wrong tag, many experts might not be able to read and answer it at all.